# How to query an XML field with a date filter

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

I have an XML field that I'm trying to query. I figured out how to return the first item, second, etc. I need to figure out how to return the item based on a date filter. A date is included in the XML field but I can't figure out the format. Here is an example of the XML field called [AMOUNT].

```
<X C="1" I="0">
  <E D="0Y56M0W0D" P="0" A="122039" />
  <E D="0Y10M0W0D" P="0" A="125739" />
  <E D="1000Y0M0W0D" P="1" A="131739" />
</X>
```

I can query to specify which item to return by using the below query.

```
SELECT 
 cast(AMOUNT as XML).value('(/X/E)[1]/@A','varchar(10)') AS [TEST],
 cast(AMOUNT as XML).value('(/X/E)[2]/@A','varchar(10)') AS [TEST2],
 cast(AMOUNT as XML).value('(/X/E)[3]/@A','varchar(10)') AS [TEST3]
FROM MEASURE
```

I need help finding a way to return the [AMOUNT] that's in effect on a specific date, let's say 2016-11-01. Below is what the front end shows the data as. There's also a [STARTDATE] field and in this case it equals 2012-01-01.

```
DATE       | MONTH | AMOUNT |
2012-01-01 |      1|  122039|
2016-09-01 |     57|  125739|
2017-07-01 |     67|  131739|
```

I need help writing a query to pull the [AMOUNT]  of 125,739 for the date filter of 2016-11-01. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: How do you get from `0Y56M0W0D` to `2012-01-01` exactly?

Comment: also, your date attribute seems to be `D` but you are querying `A`

Comment: I have no idea how it gets from 0Y56M0W0D to 2012-01-01, that's the part I'm struggling with. The query I posted was just what I've been able to come up with. I haven't tried to query the the D attribute yet since I can't figure out the date format. The only thing I can think of is the [STARTDATE] is always the first item in the XML, then add the 56M for the next date, then add 10M for the last date.

Comment: Shouldn't you ask the supplier of the XML how to interpret this date format?

Comment: I attempted that but they wouldn't help

Comment: Waw that's cruel and unusual. Well I certainly have to idea what format that is, I've never seen it. My search engine-fu didn't reveal anything either. I'd start with some serious complaints about not providing documentation. `Below is what the front end shows the data as` ... so **someone** has to know, right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the person I spoke with knew how but they said "unfortunately my hands are tied" when I asked if they could show me how to write the query. They just won't release how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the solution to the question *How is this interpreted?* but not yet to the actual question *How should I use this in a filter?*. Do you need help with this once you've understood how to read this?

```
DECLARE @d1 DATETIME={d'2012-01-01'};
DECLARE @d2 DATETIME=(SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,56,@d1));
DECLARE @d3 DATETIME=(SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,10,@d2));

SELECT @d1,@d2,@d3;
```

The string *D="0Y56M0W0D"* seems to point the **D**istance to the next date.
The string *D="0Y10M0W0D"* is the **D**istance to the following and *D="1000Y0M0W0D* points to *I am the last, because nobody is bothering what happens in 1000 years!*

### UPDATE: A fully working example

Some hints

- The first CTE reads the XML row-wise and returnes a derived table.
- Using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` allows to pick the numbers between the letters *Y, M, W and D*.
- The amount is divided by 1000 and casted to `decimal`.

As you are using SQL-Server 2008 you cannot use the cummulative `SUM() OVER()`, that's why I use a recursive CTE to traverse down your dates and add the *Distance* to the date of the previous row.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<X C="1" I="0">
  <E D="0Y56M0W0D" P="0" A="122039" />
  <E D="0Y10M0W0D" P="0" A="125739" />
  <E D="1000Y0M0W0D" P="1" A="131739" />
</X>';

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME={d'2012-01-01'};
```

--Here's the first CTE

```
WITH Shredded AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SortNr
          ,D.Dist AS Distance
          ,e.value('@P','int') AS P
          ,CAST(e.value('@A','int') AS DECIMAL(10,4))/1000 AS Amount
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(D.Dist,1,PosY-1) AS INT) AS Y
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(D.Dist,PosY+1,PosM-PosY-1) AS INT) AS M
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(D.Dist,PosM+1,PosW-PosM-1) AS INT) AS W
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(D.Dist,PosW+1,PosD-PosW-1) AS INT) AS D
    FROM  @xml.nodes('/X/E') AS A(e)
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT e.value('@D','nvarchar(100)') AS Dist) AS D
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX('Y',D.Dist) AS PosY
                      ,CHARINDEX('M',D.Dist) AS PosM
                      ,CHARINDEX('W',D.Dist) AS PosW
                      ,CHARINDEX('D',D.Dist) AS PosD
    ) AS Positions
)
```

--The recursive CTE

```
,RecCTE AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS ActualDate,*
    FROM Shredded
    WHERE SortNr=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(YEAR,r.Y,DATEADD(MONTH,r.M,DATEADD(WEEK,r.W,DATEADD(DAY,r.D,r.ActualDate))))
          ,s.*
    FROM RecCTE AS r
    INNER JOIN Shredded AS s ON s.SortNr=r.SortNr+1
)
```

--And the final query

```
SELECT * FROM RecCTE

+-------------------------+--------+-------------+---+---------------+------+----+---+---+
| ActualDate              | SortNr | Distance    | P | Amount        | Y    | M  | W | D |
+-------------------------+--------+-------------+---+---------------+------+----+---+---+
| 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1      | 0Y56M0W0D   | 0 | 122.039000000 | 0    | 56 | 0 | 0 |
+-------------------------+--------+-------------+---+---------------+------+----+---+---+
| 2016-09-01 00:00:00.000 | 2      | 0Y10M0W0D   | 0 | 125.739000000 | 0    | 10 | 0 | 0 |
+-------------------------+--------+-------------+---+---------------+------+----+---+---+
| 2017-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 3      | 1000Y0M0W0D | 1 | 131.739000000 | 1000 | 0  | 0 | 0 |
+-------------------------+--------+-------------+---+---------------+------+----+---+---+
```

Comment: Very strong deductive skills... as we are used to from you :). Still, I find it extremely weird that the OP can't get an explanation about the format about those that provide the XML.

Comment: @TT. True! It seems, that they put some effort trying to make it complicated to query this without their frontend... Not complicated enough though :-)

Comment: This is amazing! I tried to figure out how to use it in the where clause but I wasn't able to. If I'm trying to return an ID field with the ActualDate and Amount filtering by what amount is in effect as of today, how would I do that?

Comment: @AdamH, do I get this right? You want the *biggest-smaller* date to a given date? Just use something like `SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM ... WHERE ActualDate<GETDATE() ORDER BY ActualDate DESC` This would return just one row with the closest smaller ActualDate. If this solves your issue, please tick the acceptance check besides the vote counter. If there are follow-up questions, please start a new question with a link to this. Thx